# Overloaded operator=(bool) is called instead of operator=(string)

Tags: xcode, c++11, operator-overloading

I made a lib to parse JSON content with XCode and the main class `JSONObject` has the `operator=` overloaded, as you can see:

```
    class JSONObject
    {   
        //...

    public:

        JSONObject();
        ~JSONObject();

        //...

        void operator=(int);
        void operator=(long);
        void operator=(float);
        void operator=(double);
        void operator=(bool);
        void operator=(std::string);

        //...
    };
```

The issue here is that at the moment of use `operator=(string)` the `operator=(bool)`is invoked:

```
    JSONObject nItem;
    nItem = "My New Item"; // <--- Here is what the problem is founded.
    innerObj["GlossSeeAlso"]+= nItem;
```

[image]

The workaround that i found to "fix" this problem was specify the string type:

```
nItem = (string)"My New Item"; //"Fix 1"

nItem = string("My New Item"); //"Fix 2"
```

The lib and sample was compiled with:

```
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
```

The complete code can be founded [here](https://github.com/jorgemedra/JSONLib).

I will appreciate any help to understand this issue, why the `operator=(bool)` is invoked instead of `operator=(string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of the string literal `"My New Item"` is `char const[12]`. Such a type needs to be converted to one of the types that the overloaded `operator=` functions support.

Due to various conversion rules, the compiler decided, correctly, that
`char const[12]` → `char const*` → `bool` is a better conversion than `char const[12]` → `std::string`. Hence, `operator=(bool)` is called. The reason why `char const[12]` → `char const*` → `bool` is a better conversion than `char const[12]` → `std::string` is that the former is a sequence of standard conversions while the latter involves a user defined conversion.

To allow a string literal to be used in assignment, add another overload.

```
JSONObject& operator=(char const*);
```

---

**PS** You should change the return value of all the `operator=` functions to `JSONObject&` to make them idiomatic. See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) for more information.

Comment: That's correct, i made the correction and it fix the issue. The explication that you offered me makes me sense, choosing `const char*` vs `string`.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, can you explain more about make the operator idiomatic? I designed them (operatos=(long|double|string|bool) to set a value.

Comment: @JorgeOmarMedra, you are welcome. I added a link to another SO post in my answer.